# Mutual class references in C++

Tags: c++, architecture, software-design

There's some code at my company that takes the following form:

```
class ObjectA {
public:
  ObjectA(ObjectB &objectB): objectB(objectB) { }

void Initialize() { ... }

private:
  ObjectB &objectB;
};

class ObjectB {
public:
  ObjectB(ObjectA &objectA): objectA(objectA) { }

void Initialize() { ... }

private:
  ObjectA &objectA;
};
```

Basically, two classes have a mutual dependency on the other.

This in itself isn't what bothers me, *(although it's not great design IMO)*, **it's that the mutual dependencies are passed through the constructor by reference in both situations**.

So, the only way to actually construct this pair of objects *(they are both required in the application)* is to pass an incomplete reference as a dependency. To account for this, the separate `Initialize` methods are added as a 2nd stage constructor which are then called after both objects are created. Consequently, the constructors often times do nothing except assign the constructor parameters to the object internals, and initialize everything in the `Intizialize` method.

Although the code may be valid, my inclination is that this is a fundamentally flawed design for the following reasons:

1. The state of a dependent object can't be guaranteed in the
   constructor
2. It requires the developers to make an additional call to `Initialize`
3. It precludes the use of compiler warnings that check if member variables have been initialized
4. There's nothing preventing `Initialize` from being called multiple times, which can result in strange, hard to track down errors

My coworkers tell me that having a separate initialize method simplifies the object construction since the developer doesn't have to worry about what order objects are declared in the application root. They can be declared and constructed in completely arbitrary order since everything is guaranteed to be valid once Initialize gets called.

I've been advocating that object construction should follow the same order of the dependency graph and that these objects should be redesigned to remove the mutual dependency, but I wanted to see what the SO gurus had to say about it. Am I wrong to think this is bad practice?

**Edit:**

The way these classes actually get constructed is through a factory class like below:

```
Factory {
public:
  Factory():
    objectA(objectB),
    objectB(objectA) {
  }
private:
  ObjectA objectA;
  ObjectB objectB;
};
```

Comment: Well, it cannot work, references must be set as construction time, you can reinitialize them later. Use a pointer instead? But yes, seems like an odd design, but then I've seen far worse.

Comment: Well, I know it works since it's running in production code. And yes, using a pointer for one of the classes was one of my recommendations.

Comment: This code itself cannot work, how do you initialize `objectA` without an `objectB` and vice versa? Or this is not the code you have in production.

Comment: Both class instances are declared as members of an app factory class. `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` are initialized in the constructor initializer list of Factory.

Comment: So it's initialized with an incomplete object?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what is so bothersome to me. I've edited the post to show how they get constructed.

Comment: As long as in the constructor of objectA and objecB no attempts are made to access the referenced object (including taking a reference to one of its suboject), the code is standard compliant.

Comment: The interesting sentence in the standard: [class.cdtor](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.cdtor#1.sentence-1) *For an object with a non-trivial constructor, referring to any non-static member or base class of the object before the constructor begins execution results in undefined behavior*. Inside factory constructor you can take references to objectA or objectB. But you cannot not access these objects, neither take a reference to a non static data members of these objects (`int& v=objectA.x` would be undefined, but `ObjectA& v=objecta` is standard compliant)

Comment: I understand it is standard compliant. My question is whether it is generally accepted as good/bad practice.

Comment: The initialize bit: who gets initialized first, and what does it assume about initialization of the other?  Second, as noted they are mutually constructed in the same scope.  Is there any way one can own the other?  Third, is references a requirement, and if so what practical non-asthetic reason why is it required?

Comment: Could you have a boolean storing whether it's been initialised or not and in the initialised function return if that is true? not a complete answer but a suggestion to one of your points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bad practice yes. Passing a reference to `objectB` for `objectA` to work with while it's not properly initialized yet is a no-no.

It might be standard compliant and safe code now because `ObjectA` doesn't try to access the passed reference to `ObjectB` in its constructor but that safety is hanging by a thread. If later on someone decides to just initialize in the constructor or access anything from `objectB`, or change it any other way where `objectB` will be used you end up with UB.

This sounds like a use case for pointers that are reseated after both constructors have run.

Comment: Are you aware of any sources that can back up the claim that this is a 'no-no'? The code is technically standard compliant, so I'd like something authoritative to back up my opinion.

Comment: @danQ There is nothing that says its a no-no. I'm telling you it is. I'm telling you because its potentially dangerous and easily overlooked. There isn't a big authoritive C++ guide really unlike other languages. There's the standard, and your code currently follows it correctly. I say currently for a reason since it's really easy to mess that up right now, it's fragile. That's why im saying it's a no-no. There's The C++ faq but it doesn't really contain this. You'll have to take it from me, a chicken.

Answer (score 1):

I too don't like the code as posted - it is unnecessarily complicated and fragile.  There is usually some concept of ownership when two classes cooperate like this, so, if objects of type `A` own objects of type `B` (which they probably should), then you would do something like:

```
#include <memory>

class A;

class B
{
public:
    B (A& a) : a (a) { }
private:
    A& a;
};

class A
{
public:
    A () { b = std::make_unique <B> (*this); }

private:
    std::unique_ptr <B> b;
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eq9e082rRsUskSOK)

Comment: What would you say to the argument that ownership doesn't apply because the lifetime of the app is forever? (It's an embedded system)

Comment: No offense intended, but I would still say "write sensible code"

Comment: None taken, I agree with you :)